# Can I control the mouse cursor from within R?

Tags: r, keyboard, mouse, rjava

Is it possible, to control the mouse pointer from the R console?

I have something like this in mind:

```
move_mouse(x_pos=100,y_pos=200)   # move the mouse pointer to position (100,200)
mouse_left_button_down            # simulate a press of the left button
move_mouse(x_pos=120,y_pos=250)   # move mouse to select something
mouse_release_left_button          # release the pressed button
```

In MATLAB, something like this is possible with the following code

```
import java.awt.Robot;
mouse = Robot;
mouse.mouseMove(0, 0);
mouse.mouseMove(100, 200);
```

I tried a direct conversion of the above into R that looks like this:

```
install.packages("rJava")          # install package
library(rJava)                     # load package
.jinit()                           # this starts the JVM
jRobot <- .jnew("java/awt/Robot")  # Create object of the Robot class
```

Once I got jRobot in R, I tried to call its metho "MouseMove(100,200)" using the two command below which both resulted in an error.

```
jRobot$mouseMove(10,10)

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
```

or

```
.jcall(jRobot,, "mouseMove",10,10)
Error in .jcall(jRobot, , "mouseMove", 10, 10) : 
              method mouseMove with signature (DD)V not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. You have to tell R that 100 is an integer, in order to pass it to java correctly.

```
install.packages("rJava")          # install package
library(rJava)                     # load package
.jinit()                           # this starts the JVM
jRobot <- .jnew("java/awt/Robot")  # Create object of the Robot class

# Let java sleep 500 millis between the simulated mouse events
.jcall(jRobot,, "setAutoDelay",as.integer(500))

# move mouse to 100,200 and select the text up to (100,300)         
.jcall(jRobot,, "mouseMove",as.integer(100),as.integer(200))
.jcall(jRobot,, "mousePress",as.integer(16))
.jcall(jRobot,, "mouseMove",as.integer(100),as.integer(300))
.jcall(jRobot,, "mouseRelease",as.integer(16))
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 2017, CRAN has a package called `rMouse` to handle mouse movement.

```
library(rMouse)
move(0,0)       # move to top left corner (0,0)
move(50,30)     # move to pixel x = 50, y = 30
left()          # left click
right()         # right click
```

Under the hood it still uses Java's robot.

Similarly, `KeyboardSimulator` package published in 2018 seems to be doing pretty much the same thing

Comment: As of 2021, this package is no longer available on CRAN

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows, `library(KeyboardSimulator)` is the easiest way.

You can use it to make a bot in R

see the example:
[Move Mouse in R (RStudio)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqp5atsLlJc&t=150s)
[make a bot in R (Rstudio) for social media](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWAokJdDP4g)

Answer (score 3):

What operating system? In Linux, you could use `xdotool` and call it from the R `system` function.

```
> mousemove=function(x,y){system(paste0("xdotool mousemove ",x," ",y))}
> mousemove(0,0)
> mousemove(500,500)
```

Note these are screen coordinates, nothing to do with the coordinates in your R graphics window, but you weren't clear about what you wanted. You might be able to get the screen coords of your R graphics window with some other X11 utilities and position on a plot if that's what you want.

In Windows, there's probably some other mouse-tweaking program you can leech onto. IDK.

xdotool info: http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse

further reading of that article shows how to activate particular windows and do mouse actions in them.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have to run this on a Windows machine :-(
But I get your idea. I could write a little program in .NET for example, compile it to an .exe and run it using the "system" command in R.
Did I get your idea right?

Comment: Yep - if you write C++ you could use Rcpp, call it in a more integrated way, and put it in a package. You definitely have to do it at the operating system level though, there's no R functions to do this.

Comment: This is a solution that should definitely work. But I still have some hope that it is possible somehow to the external methods directly from R. Using e.g. the java.awt.robot seams a bit more elegant to me.